# How to check whether your code environment on Windows or on Linux or other OS

Tags: php, linux, apache, iis, wordpress

right now, i code custom wordpress theme and testing it in xampp windows XP on apache server. But as long as i concern, there's no wp build-in function to identify the code environment. Is there's any PHP build-in function to identify such thing ?

for the record, what i want to code need to read a directory. in my apache (in windows), the path will be c:/xampp/htdocs where apache on linux will be \somepath\somepath\

so, is there any code solution to know what is the OS environment without i have to retrieve and compare the path ? i hope it will also work on other OS with other webserver then APACHE such as IIS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`php_uname()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-uname.php) for this, and possibly [`php_sapi_name()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php).

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']` should do it for you.  Use `strpos` to look for Win32 or Unix.

Comment: thanks, i will look into it. This solution is for Apache only or can be use on other OS environment ?

Comment: Not sure, it's part of the PHP specs, so I would assume any OS environment.